# MAX(Date) Query running very slow - MySQL

Tags: mysql

The below query is running very slow as the table is very huge and I just want to select a max of date form the table, I have some id1,id2, and date column as PK. Any trick to fetch it faster?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(MAX(Date), INTERVAL 2 DAY), "%Y-%m-%d %H:00")  
FROM mytable.
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Vijay

Comment: Not much you can do here... `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date - INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') x FROM mytable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;` ?

Comment: Create Index on column date.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your query to be fast on a huge table (as you mention) you'll need to create an index on the specific column. For example:

```
create index ix1 on mytable (Date);
```

Also, avoid naming columns with reserved words such as `Date`. It'll make your queries more complicated.

Comment: Date isn't a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry Though, I totally agree with you, I think it's better to avoid identifier like this one. Maybe I'm paranoid. :|